# How to add "React Performance DevTools" as chrome extension in electron app using package "electron-devtool-installer"

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, electron, react-devtools

I am trying to add "react-performance-devtool" extension to electron app using electron-devtool-installer.

When i tried with one of the mentioned extension in documentation, it is working fine, but with any other extension i am getting error.

I am trying something like this:

```
  const installer = require("electron-devtools-installer");
  const forceDownload = !!process.env.UPGRADE_EXTENSIONS;
  const extensions = [
    "REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS",
    "REDUX_DEVTOOLS",
    "REACT_PERFORMANCE_DEVTOOLS"
  ];

  return Promise.all(
    extensions.map(name => installer.default(installer[name], forceDownload))
  ).catch(console.log);
};
```

I got the below Error:

```
Error: Invalid extensionReference passed in: "undefined"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const REACT_PERFORMANCE_DEVTOOLS = {
  id: "fcombecpigkkfcbfaeikoeegkmkjfbfm",
  electron: "^4.0.5"
};

const installExtensions = async () => {
  const installer = require("electron-devtools-installer");
  const forceDownload = !!process.env.UPGRADE_EXTENSIONS;
  const extensions = [
    "REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS",
    "REDUX_DEVTOOLS",
    "REACT_PERF",
    REACT_PERFORMANCE_DEVTOOLS
  ];

  return Promise.all(
    extensions.map(name =>
      installer.default(installer[name] || name, forceDownload)
    )
  ).catch(console.log);
};
```

REACT_PERFORMANCE_DEVTOOLS passing as name works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used `REACT_DEVTOOLS` instead of `REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS`

ts didn't highlighted it.

`electron-devtools-installer` used to bad practice, as naming is not consistent:

```
VUEJS_DEVTOOLS
VUEJS3_DEVTOOLS
REDUX_DEVTOOLS
MOBX_DEVTOOLS
```

but:

```
APOLLO_DEVELOPER_TOOLS
REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS
```

even more!:

```
CYCLEJS_DEVTOOL
```